# Why can I add a single row/column element in Pandas, while not being able to adding using a list of rows or columns

Tags: python, pandas

when adding now data to a dataframe, how come this works for adding in a single row and column:

```
df.loc[len(df),NewCol] = NewData
```

but the following doesn't work for adding in multiple columns?

```
df.loc[len(df),[NewCol,NewCol2,NewCol3]] = [NewData1,NewData2,NewData3]
```

and this doesn't work for adding multiple of data

```
df.loc[[len(df),len(df)+1,len(df)+2],NewCol] = [NewColData1, NewColData2,NewColData3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) if you want to add multiple columns.

```py
import datetime as dt
d = list(pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2020,7,1), dt.datetime(2020,7,2), freq="15min"))
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":d, 
      "Scaled":[round(Decimal(random.uniform(0, 1)),6) for x in d]})

df.assign(c1=[round(Decimal(random.uniform(0, 1)),6) for x in d],
         c2=[round(Decimal(random.uniform(0, 1)),6) for x in d])

df.assign(**{f"c{i}":[round(Decimal(random.uniform(0, 1)),6) for x in d] for i in range(5)})
```